Ros2 control with nav2 problem
I am using ros2 control to drive a four wheel robot every thing is working well when i move it using teleop keyboard aline but when i am using slam toolbox to generate a map or even used a previously generated map the robot behavior are unpredictable and the odom moves and moves robot randomly

Please give more information of your setup, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
